# ¿Parabén o parabeno?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, plurales, terminología

Hace ya unos años que las compañías de cosmética vienen anunciando la ausencia de productos dañinos o sospechosos en sus fórmulas. Uno de ellos es una serie de productos generalmente sintéticos con un anillo fenílico llamados *parabens* en inglés.

Hay cierta disparidad entre las etiquetas de cada marca acerca de cómo escribir dicha palabra en español, y cuál es su plural.

- Parabeno, plural parabenos
- Parabén, plural parabenos
- Parabén, plural parabenes
- probablemente otras

Tengo mi propia teoría al respecto, la cual no expresaré si no me la pedís para no influir en las respuestas. Pero me gustaría contar con fuentes de autoridad acerca de cuál es la opción correcta o si éstas no existen (o no hay consenso entre ellas) y debemos aceptar el uso más frecuente.

Comment: Puede ser que se acepte más de una? Esta entreada de la [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabeno) (lo sé, no es la fuente más fiable, pero creo que la palabra todavía no está en el DRAE) usa _parabeno_ para el singular y " parabenos, o parabenes" como posibles plurales. Creo que no usa "parabén" como forma singular en el artículo.

Comment: Hola @diego precisamente mi postura coincide con la que aparece reflejada en el comentario anónimo de 2011 en la "Talk page" de esa misma entrada ;) Estaba buscando algo donde fundamentar esa postura, o bien abandonarla por otra.

Comment: El argumento del comentario en la wiki no me parece muy sólido: podemos perfectamente considerar que *parabeno* es contracción de PARAhidroxiBENzoatO, manteniendo la letra final, lo que es propio de las abreviaturas en castellano. La contracción puede acabar en *-eno* por asimilación con otros nombres de moléculas orgánicas, como los alquenos o el propio benceno. Por cierto, en la nomenclatura de la Real Academia de Ciencias no he encontrado nada.

Comment: Sólo por el gusto de discutir y por añadir flacos que quizás lleven a algún lado quizás no: ¿puede ser que *-eno* esté reservado a CH3-(CH2)n-CH3? En el sentido de que un *-ato* implica R-COOH y llamarle *-eno* (o cualquier otro sufijo ya en uso) confunda. ¿Hay algún organismo —tipo IUPAC— que regule las nomenclaturas comerciales en español? ¿O por ser comerciales escapan a regulación? ¿Hay que registrar esos nombres en algún sitio equivalente a la FDA? Quizás ahí encontraríamos la respuesta (al menos para el singular).

Comment: Por cierto @Diego ¡gracias por añadir recompensa! ¿Puedo poner algo yo de mi parte?

Comment: No puedo editar mi comentario anterior, en vez de CH3-(CH2)n-CH3 supongo que tendría que haber escrito Cn-H2n

Comment: @guillem, aparte de aceptar una respuesta el día que la obtengamos, creo que puedes ayudar a otorgar la recompensa en puntos a la respuesta que creas que lo merezca.

Comment: Si bien _parabens_ es una abreviatura del idioma inglés, que corresponde a _para-hydroxybenzoic_ mi sugerencia es que busques en un foro de químicos, si quieres encontrar una abreviatura aceptada por la academia, para el uso del ácido 4-hidroxibenzoico, p-Hidroxibenzoico o para-Hidroxibenzoico. Por ser compuesto químico y peor, abreviatura, no se encuentra en los traductores ya que existen unas reglas definidas para nombrarlos.

Comment: Difícil pregunta!

Comment: La recompensa para esta pregunta va a expirar en menos de 24 horas y no hay ninguna respuesta todavía. Aunque quizá no se pueda responder de manera rotunda, quizá alguien quiera intentar proponer algo? Algunos de los comentarios podrían considerarse una respuesta decente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desde el punto de vista de la nomenclatura química, lo más <strike>correcto</strike> preciso sería llamarlos **parahidroxibenzoatos**, y de hecho se puede encontrar que hay quien los denomina así.

Pero cuando se trata de un nombre general para un grupo de compuestos químicos en la práctica no hay mucha nomenclatura que valga, ya que además  destacar la estructura  química común, que se puede describir de varias formas, además deber ser simple, pegadizo y pronunciable.

Según se mire la fórmula general de los parabenos, se pueden ver un fenol (= hidroxibenceno) y un grupo variable con un enlace éster (benzoatos), o podemos  ver simplemente dos radicales opuestos (en posición «**para**»: en un lado el `-OH` y en el otro el `-CO-OR`) en un anillo de **be**nce**no**.Por ello tampoco falta quien les llama **parabencenos**, si bien es un término mucho más general (ya que cabe cualquier tipo de radicales, con tal de que estén en posición «*para*»). Pero es más simple y puede que  «parabenos» en parte derive, o simplemetne haya tenido más aceptació,n porque es también una contracción de «**parabe**nce**no**».

En cuanto a «parabén», como comentaba Sergio es evidente que deriva del inglés «paraben» que también encaja como contracción de «**parabenzene**». Por tanto, en mi opinión no deberia usarse (ni en singular, ni en plural).

Comment: En la misma línea ¿podríamos decir, pues, que «acetaminofeno» es más correcto (o está mejor adaptado) que «acetaminofén» aunque sea éste último el más usado?

Comment: @guilem Eso creo. Supongo que «acetaminofén» es simplemente la castellanización del inglés «acetaminophen». Por otro lado,  «acetaminofeno» debería ser en realidad «acetaminofenol»  si es una  simplificación de  p-acetaminophenol o nombres químicos clásicos similares (atendiendo a la IUPAC, debería ser «hidroxifenilacetamida», o vaya usted a saber ...), de donde supongo que también deriva por contracción el sinónimo más usado en España:   «paracetamol».